# Save Logic App runs to a database

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I want to be able to log my Logic App runs and display them in a my own app. Just metadata like if the run was Successfull/Failed, ID etc.
Is there any way to save the runs and store them in a database or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the preview version of logicapps sdk to get this information. refer this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/logic-apps-net-sdk-available/

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell command Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory returns exactly what you want. This can be stored in specific format (e.g. JSON) in database (e.g. blob) and use in your app.